# AWS IAM role creation for serverless framework - Best Practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I manage the AWS security in my company.

We by default do not provide IAM role creation permissions to our developers.

But here is the problem, how should we handle this for developers who are using serverless framework to deploy their workloads?

Should we allow them to create IAM roles and have serverless framework to manage the permissions for those roles? or should we precreate the custom roles for this and ask developers to use that Role ARN in `serverless.yml` or should we use IAM permissions boundary?

Can some one please help ?

Answer (score 3):

It's really hard to tailor the permissions needed by the serverless. In my opinion, the developers should have full AWS  access at least to test environments in order to learn and experiment. If you are worried about accidental damage to production resources, you can only make changes to production via CICD tools. You may still have to temporarily grant permission to developers to do the initial configurations.

Comment: thanks @Arunmainthan, we cannot provide the full access even to development environment due to internal policy as we treat development env as production from security perspective.

Comment: Have a look at this “Serverless Framework: Minimal IAM role Permissions” by David Przybilla https://link.medium.com/KxQz953xV1 . I haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 2):

What you would want to do is use the [Permissions Boundary](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/delegate-permission-management-to-developers-using-iam-permissions-boundaries/) feature provided by AWS. With this feature, the effective permissions the devs / serverless stacks would have is the `intersection` of the policies defined in the IAM role and the permissions boundary.

For example, lets say that you have allowed your devs to create IAM roles and policies for Lambda functions. You also have defined a permissions boundary with only S3 read access. Now if the devs were to create a serverless stack with Lambda permissions with the AdministratorAccess policy, they would have to include the permissions boundary in the role and the *effective permissions* that your Lambda functions would have is just S3 read access.

There is a good [blog post](https://blog.smirnov.la/how-to-control-permission-of-iam-role-created-within-cloudformation-stack-d2ac975ecc80) explaining this implementation in CloudFormation you can modify it to work with Serverless templates. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

One developer friendly approach would be using several accounts, combined with locking down the production account more than the testing account(s) developers use.

As mentioned in @captainblack's previous answers, a Permissions Boundary can be one tool to restrict potential damage in production. We use it in addition to function specific roles / SAST scanning in our CI/CD environment and enforce all newly created roles to adhere to the defined boundary in production.

For the Serverless Framework you can implement it like this (**[account]** is your account id):

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.9
  rolePermissionsBoundary: arn:aws:iam::[acccount]:policy/permission_boundary
```

This way all roles serverless creates will inherit the permissions boundary from the provider settings.